# Default Application for .pdf View being Overridden to Chrome

Tags: file-association

I have an interesting problem that has been vexing me for the past few weeks: I have a user who uses Adobe Reader to open .pdf file formats (which is pretty standard). However, Windows (or something) keeps setting Chrome as the default application to open .pdf files. It's an easy change, but it gets reverted at some point during the day. The change is somewhat sporadic, and it doesn't even seem to be during a login or reboot. That is, it will revert back to using Chrome during regular use of the computer.

I have tried many different things. I've reinstalled Chrome, set Windows to always use Adobe to open .pdf files (in the "open as" dialog and in the "choose default apps by file type" menu) and done some reading online, but I have come up empty handed.

Obviously this isn't catastrophic, but it certainly is perplexing, and I'm interested in what is causing it. I have never seen this happen before on any version of Windows, ever.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. Try the solution below. Someone else posted the same issue on Google forums. Hope it helps.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/bWRzK-7q0l8/2dWcG5FhAgAJ

> There might be chances that your user profile account might have been
>   corrupted. Try creating a new one and check on the off chance that it
>   makes any difference:
>
> - Exit Google Chrome completely. Enter the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open Windows Explorer.
> - In the Windows Explorer window that appears enter `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\` in the address bar.
> - Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default."
> - Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.
>
> Once done, uninstall and reinstall Chrome again. You can also try the
>   [Google Chrome alternate
>   installer](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/126299?hl=en&rd=1)
>   which allows you to install Chrome while being offline. Once
>   installed, Chrome gets automatically updated whenever there is a new
>   version available.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I missed this in my search. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: No problem. Please do.